# .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.7.1 migrations

Tags: .net, migration

I am migrating our project from *.Net 2* to .*Net 4.7.1* but I am facing the general problem that is:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Managers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

I have tried to make assembly strongName and then reference it to the project but it unfortunately could not solve my problem. Could you please give me a properly solution about this problem.

Comment: The PublickeyToken value with null value seems strange. have you added the right PublicKeyToken in the reference?

Comment: I suggest to don't sign assembly according with [dotnet documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/strong-name-signing.md#1-microsoft-strong-names-their-assemblies-should-i).

Comment: We don't sign assembly and i run this command on powershall to get publickeytoken and it gives me null. PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ([system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile("c:\Managers.dll")).FullName
Managers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: The error show the reference is to a signed assembly...i'd follow that lead.

Comment: I checked the assembly from properties. Strong Name=false. If it is signed it would be true im i wrong?

Comment: You are right. Consider another thing: both projects must have StrongName=false.

Comment: Both projects have strongname=false.

Comment: One more thing managers use  excel.dll that is signed. strongname=true. can this cause problem?

Comment: Yes, id excel.dll is signed, so all the dll who interacts with that should be signed

Comment: This excel.dll interacts many DLL but many of them is not signed. Alright if i change excel.dll to usigned DLL would it work properly? We do not want to sign all dll. What do you think about that? Can you give me a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, if you remove all signed referenced assembly you shouldn't have any problems. I think this is the right way.

Comment: There are many 3rd party DLL that should be signed and of course they are signed. What about that?

Comment: If you need to interact with a library and that library exists only signed, you library should be signed. Usually 3rd part libraries exists both signed and not, to cover all cases. If a library does not have a unsigned version, in my opinion, you should evaluate a change.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work :(

Comment: Can you share your .csproj files?

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for your help. I solve the problem. We are working on a big project and this project depends many project. So one of these project had been signed. The problem occur this project. I unsigned this projects assembly and then problem solved.